# In Python increment variable by a rule defined as a value in a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to make kind of pre-defined rules for incrementing some variables. I'm trying to do this by making a dictionary where the rule is linked to some key. Then, in the loop, I reference the key. I thought that it would be equivalent to setting:

```
i = i+1
```

to say

```
i=Coord['DR'][0]
```

But that's not what I'm finding. Here is a script that replicates the error:

```
i =0
j =0
LL = 0
Coord ={
'DR':[i+1,j+1]
}
while LL <=10:
    Choice = 'DR'
    print i,j
    i = Coord[Choice][0]
    j = Coord[Choice][1]
    LL +=1
```

the current output:

```
0 0
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
1 1
```

I want:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 10
```

Answer (score 3):

After the initial six lines, `Coord['DR']` will be `[1, 1]` (because `i + 1` is `0 + 1`, which is `1`; similar for `j`). You want something that can calculate for you... A function! Or a lambda!

```
i =0
j =0
LL = 0
Coord ={
'DR':[lambda i: i + 1, lambda j: j + 1]
}
while LL <=10:
    Choice = 'DR'
    print i,j
    i = Coord[Choice][0](i)
    j = Coord[Choice][1](j)
    LL +=1
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "a lambda". `lambda` is just syntax for defining a function, exactly as `def` is syntax for defining a function; either way, the thing you get is a function (the same type of function and everything).

Comment: @abamert: Of course there is such a thing as a lambda: exactly as you say, a syntactic construct of creating an anonymous function. When you say just "function", usually you think of a named function, in Python created using `def`. While there is no underlying content-wise difference between a named function and an unnamed one, they do make distinct syntactic "things". And saying "A named function! Or an unnamed function!" lacks punch.

Comment: First, if you're only thinking of named functions when you say "function", that's a confusion that should be fixed. It is important that functions are all functions. There are an awful lot of people who seem to believe that functions and "lambdas" are different kinds of things—and therefore don't know that one of them can be passed as an argument or stored in a dict or whatever. That's not a good thing, and writing in a way that misleads more people into thinking that way isn't helping. And explicitly contrasting "a function" with "a lambda" is definitely misleading n exactly that way.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
Coord ={
'DR':[i+1,j+1]
}
```

That just evaluates `i+1` and `j+1` and stores the resulting values—`1` and `1`—in `Coord['DR']`.

The fact that you later reassign `i` to some other value than `0` doesn't mean that the number `1` suddenly changes into a different number. If you could do that, you could break the universe.

There are two reasons you could be confused about this.

You might expect Python to store expressions that are lazily evaluated on demand. It doesn't. It stores values. If you want an expression that's lazily evaluated on demand, you need to do that explicitly, with a function.

Alternatively, you might expect Python to store references to variables. It doesn't. It stores references to *values*. This one, you can't even do explicitly. Variables aren't real "things", they're just names for values. When you reassign `i` to some other value, like `i = i + 1`, that's just saying that `i` is now a name for `1` instead of a name for `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object-oriented approach and define`Rule`objects. For this particular case you could use the indexing operator and make it have the side-effect of incrementing the proper variable.

```
i = 0
j = 0

class Rule1(object):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            return i+1
        elif index == 1:
            return j+1
        else:
            raise IndexError()

Coord = {'DR': Rule1()}

LL = 0
while LL <= 10:
    Choice = 'DR'
    print i, j
    i = Coord[Choice][0]
    j = Coord[Choice][1]
    LL += 1
```

The one in the example is so simple and didn't even need an`__init__()`constructor, but others could, which would allow for some fairly sophisticated`Rule`-type classes to be defined and used, plus they would facilitate code-reuse — for example you could add constructors to them to specify specific values that affected what they did, effectively parameterizing them.

Comment: What's the advantage of OO over `Coord ={'DR':[lambda i: i + 1, lambda j: j + 1]}`? The OO method appears to require much more code to define the rules (there are about 8).

Comment: One advantage in this case is that it made it possible to make your proposed example loop code work unchanged -- where simply indexing the `Rule` object does what you want by implementing the class's indexing mechanism via the special method `__getitem__()`. This approach would allow many different types of "Rules" and allow defining parametrized versions of them. For example one that could increment different amounts or ways depending on argument(s) passed once to its constructor (if it had one). Bottomline flexibility and extensibility. Using the least amount of code is not allows the goal.